# Angular reactive form custom validation, for the entire formGroup at the same time

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, customvalidator

I have this form:

> ```
> EDI_TRANSACTION_VALIDATORS = this.formBuilder.group({
>         'eligibilitySettings': this.formBuilder.group({
>             'id': [0],
>             'ediPartnerId': ['', []],
>             'ediPayerMasterId': ['',[]],
>             'evvMasterId': ['',[]],
>             'ediStationId': [''],
>             'other': [''],
>             'payerId': [''],
>             'payerPortalUrl': [''],
>             'primarySystem': [''],
>             'transactionSystemType':[''],
>             'useStationIdAsAuthPrefix':[''],
>             'ediClearingHouse':[false],
>             'evvSystem':[false],
>             'payerPortal':[false],
>             'otherCheckbox':[false],
>             'state':['']
>         }, {validator: this.conditionallyRequiredValidator('ediClearingHouse',
> ```
>
> 'ediPartnerId', 'ediPayerMasterId', 'primarySystem',
> 'evvSystem','evvMasterId')}),

and this function for validate the form, this funtion works

> ```
>  conditionallyRequiredValidator(controlLabelConditional1: string, controlLabelRequired1: string, controlLabelRequired2?: string,
> ```
>
> controlLabelRequired3?: string, controlLabelConditional2?: string,
> controlLabelRequired4?: string) {
> return (group: FormGroup): {[key: string]: any} => {
> const masterControl = group.controls[controlLabelConditional1];
> const masterControl2 = group.controls[controlLabelConditional2];
> const controlRequired1 = group.controls[controlLabelRequired1];
> const controlRequired2 = group.controls[controlLabelRequired2];
> const controlRequired3 = group.controls[controlLabelRequired3];
> const controlRequired4 = group.controls[controlLabelRequired4];
> if (masterControl.value && masterControl2.value) {
> return Validators.required(controlRequired1),Validators.required(controlRequired2),Validators.required(controlRequired3),Validators.required(controlRequired4)
> }
> else if(masterControl.value && !masterControl2.value){
> return Validators.required(controlRequired1),Validators.required(controlRequired2)
> }
> else if(masterControl2.value && !masterControl.value){
> return Validators.required(controlRequired4)
> }
> controlRequired1.setErrors(null);
> controlRequired2.setErrors(null);
> controlRequired3.setErrors(null);
> controlRequired4.setErrors(null);
> return null;
> }
> }

the problem is that I need something like this more dynamically, that I can apply validators required to many controls at the same time.

> ```
>    }, { validator: this.conditionallyRequiredValidator([{ controlLabel: 'ediClearingHouse', controlsLabelRequired:
> ```
>
> ['ediPartnerId', 'ediPayerMasterId'] }, { controlLabel: 'evvSystem',
> controlsLabelRequired: ['evvMasterId'] }]) }),
> 'payerType': [''],
> });
>
> ```
> conditionallyRequiredValidator(conditionallyRequired: any) {
>     return (group: FormGroup): { [key: string]: any } => {
>         conditionallyRequired.forEach(element => {
>             if (group.controls[element.controlLabel].value)
>                 element.controlsLabelRequired.forEach(controlLabelRequired => {
>                     Validators.required(group.controls[controlLabelRequired]);
>                 })
>                 else {
>                     element.controlsLabelRequired.forEach(controlLabelRequired => {
>                         group.controls[controlLabelRequired].setErrors(null);
>                     })
>                 }
>         });
>         return null;
>     }
> }
> ```